# API request consistently takes 21 seconds per request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, api, heroku

So, 21 seconds per request, snippet.json, and the images.  My widget loads in 42 seconds.  consistently.  That just seems weird.

**widget.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function fetchJSONFile(path, callback) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
          var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
          if (callback) callback(data);
        };
      };
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', path);
    httpRequest.send(); 
  }

  // this requires the file and executes a callback with the parsed result once available
  fetchJSONFile('http://ecorebox.com/companies/1/snippet.json', function(data){
    // do what you do
    var trees = data['trees'];
    var water = data['water'];
    var energy = data['electricity'];
    var widget = document.createElement("div");
    widget.id = 'erb_widget';
    widget.style.width = "200px";
    widget.style.height = "400px";
    widget.style.font = '14px';
    widget.style.src = "local('Oswald Light'), local('Oswald-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oswald/v7/HqHm7BVC_nzzTui2lzQTDT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff')";
    widget.style.color = '#666';
    widget.style.border = 'solid 1px #666';
    var logo = document.createElement("div");
    logo.id = 'erbw_logo';
    logo.style.background = "url(http://ecorebox.com/assets/narrow_200px_logo.png) no-repeat";
    logo.style.height = '29px';
    logo.style.width = '109px';
    logo.style.margin = '20px auto';
    var txt = document.createElement("div");
    txt.id = 'erbw_txt';
    txt.style.font = 'bold 13px';
    txt.style.margin = '5px';
    var cs_trees = document.createElement("div");
    cs_trees.id = 'erbw_cs_trees';
    cs_trees.style.background = "url(http://ecorebox.com/assets/erbw_ico_tree.png) no-repeat";
    cs_trees.style.height = '61px';
    cs_trees.style.margin = '20px';
    cs_trees.innerHTML = "<div style='margin: 12px auto auto 62px; font: 14px bold;'><span style='font: 22px bolder'>" + trees + "</span><br/>Trees Saved</div>";
    var cs_water = document.createElement("div");
    cs_water.id = 'erbw_cs_water';
    cs_water.style.background = "url(http://ecorebox.com/assets/erbw_ico_water.png) no-repeat";
    cs_water.style.height = '61px';
    cs_water.style.margin = '20px';
    cs_water.innerHTML = "<div style='margin: 12px auto auto 62px; font: 14px bold;'><span style='font: 22px bolder'>" + water + "</span><br/>Gallons of Water Conserved</div>";
    var cs_energy = document.createElement("div");
    cs_energy.id = 'erbw_cs_energy';
    cs_energy.style.background = "url(http://ecorebox.com/assets/erbw_ico_energy.png) no-repeat";
    cs_energy.style.height = '61px';
    cs_energy.style.margin = '20px';
    cs_energy.innerHTML = "<div style='margin: 12px auto auto 62px; font: 14px bold;'><span style='font: 22px bolder'>" + energy + "</span><br/>kWh Energy Saved</div>";
    var footer = document.createElement("div");
    footer.id = 'erbw_footer';
    footer.style.font = 'bolder 14px';
    footer.style.textAlign = 'center';
    footer.style.padding = '10px';
    footer.style.margin = '10px';
    footer.innerHTML = "Learn more at<br/><a href='http://www.ecorebox.com' target='_blank'>www.ecorebox.com</a><br/>(877) REBOX IT";

    // this appends the div to the site.  will be different for each client
    $('.content').append(widget);
    document.getElementById('erb_widget').appendChild(logo);
    document.getElementById('erb_widget').appendChild(txt);
    document.getElementById('erb_widget').appendChild(cs_trees);
    document.getElementById('erb_widget').appendChild(cs_water);
    document.getElementById('erb_widget').appendChild(cs_energy);
    document.getElementById('erb_widget').appendChild(footer);

  });
</script>
```

To see it in action, check out http://alphabeticdesign.com/test - Eco ReBox is a rails app hosted on Heroku.  I'm not sure which code I'd have to show you from there for this to make sense... let me know, and I'll pull it up.

Comment: The response time generally has nothing to do with the client. Have you tried using the Chrome Dev tools networking timeline to identify what's causing the delay?

Comment: The Chrome dev tools are what tell me it's taking exactly 21 seconds.  if you go to the `json` directly http://www.ecorebox.com/companies/4/snippet.json it's instantaneous.

Comment: It takes me 1.0x seconds to load this page. Not sure where the issue is.

Comment: http://ecorebox.com/companies/1/snippet.json does not load for me.

Comment: @kobaltz the page itself loads quickly... but if you wait (42 seconds) a banner will pop up.  it's not a 'pop up' per se, but you'll see.

Comment: Gotcha. Looked at their site and it is going extremely slow as well. Chances are, it has nothing to do with your site, but rather where you're trying to pull information from. You may also want to consider hosting the files on your server instead of hotlinking.

Comment: It looks fine on my end as well. It has to do with the service provider, not you.

Comment: you guys just inadvertently answered the question... http://ecorebox.com/companies/1/snippet.json is the problem.  http://WWW.ecorebox.com/companies/1/snippet.json works with the quickness!  simply adding the `www` did it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where my api calls were taking 21 seconds consistently in Windows 7, I found the problem to be in proxy settings.  I went to Internet Options/Connections/LAN Settings and unchecked 'Automatically detect settings'.  My api call went down to 700ms.  I'm guessing it is some sort of timeout occurring while it 'detects settings'...